# How to I create an AVG of a column when another condition is met

Tags: mysql, sql, database, average

I need to calculate the average of a score column, when another column value is equal to something specific. However, my calculation is calculating the average of ALL the score columns, ignoring my condition.

The end result to is to calculate all of the score values, based on whether the progress column was each of the progress values. Eg. 'Higher than expected','Expected' etc. I am only showing all the rows for testing.

```
SELECT 
tbl_score.score,
tbl_progress.progress
(SELECT AVG(tbl_score.score) FROM tbl_score WHERE tbl_progress.progress = 'Expected') as expectedAv
FROM tbl_score
JOIN tbl_pupil ON tbl_score.pupilID = tbl_pupil.pupilID 
JOIN tbl_test ON tbl_score.testID = tbl_test.testID 
LEFT JOIN tbl_progress ON tbl_pupil.pupilID = tbl_progress.pupilID AND tbl_test.testID = tbl_progress.testID 
WHERE
tbl_test.schoolproviderID=16 AND tbl_test.schoolproductID=32 AND tbl_test.imported=1
ORDER by tbl_progress.progress
```

However, results look like this showing the av calculation is actually calculating the average of ALL the scores.

[image]

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: The subquery needs to be correlated with the main query.

Comment: You're missing a comma after `tbl_progress.progress`, how is that query running at all?

Comment: That's me just copying it over and editing incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use analytical function as follows:

```
select score, progress, 
       sum(case when progress = 'Expected' then score end) over (partition by progress) 
       / count(case when progress = 'Expected' then 1 end) over (partition by progress) 
       as avg_
from your_Table
```

If you want to implement the solution in your own query then you can replace

```
(SELECT AVG(tbl_score.score) FROM tbl_score WHERE tbl_progress.progress = 'Expected') 
 as expectedAv
```

with

```
sum(case when tbl_progress.progress = 'Expected' then tbl_score.score end) 
    over (partition by tbl_progress.progress) 
 / count(case when tbl_progress.progress = 'Expected' then 1 end) 
     over (partition by tbl_progress.progress) as expectedAv
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want a window function:

```
SELECT s.score, pr.progress,
       AVG(s.score) OVER (PARTITION BY pr.progress) as expectedAvg
FROM tbl_score s JOIn
     tbl_pupil p
     ON s.pupilID = p.pupilID JOIN
     tbl_test t
     ON s.testID = t.testID LEFT JOIN
     tbl_progress pr
     ON p.pupilID = pr.pupilID AND
        t.testID = pr.testID 
WHERE t.schoolproviderID = 16 AND
      t.schoolproductID = 32 AND
      t.imported = 1
ORDER by pr.progress;
```

Note that I also introduced table aliases.  These make the query easier to write and to read.